# Problems with ordering for geom_segment chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would appreciate any advice with my plot - I am a ggplot novice!

I am trying to create a cleveland dot plot faceted by cluster, which has 3 levels. I have 3 issues that I am struggling with:

1. Within each cluster, I want the dots to be ordered by my continuous x-var. The code below isn't ordering correctly.
2. Is it possible to change the dot type based on whether the y-var ends in a 0 (does not have a characteristic) or 1 (does have the characteristic)?
3. I have a variable in my data set (Population) which shows the population % of a characteristic. I would like to see if a cluster characteristic is over/under-represented compared with the population. I would like to add a dot on the same line of each y-var.

Here is my code :

```
ggplot(cl1, aes(x=Cluster_prop, y=reorder(Var, Cluster_prop)))+
  geom_segment(aes(yend=Var), xend=0, colour="grey50")+
  geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=Cluster))+
  facet_grid(Cluster~., scales="free_y", space="free_y") +
  ggtitle("Top 10 Cluster Characteristics: % Children Within Cluster With 
Feature")
```

Here is my data:

```
> dput(cl1)
structure(list(Var = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 22L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 21L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 
15L, 17L, 21L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("asthdoc_1", 
"AttacksOnExer_1_0", "AttacksTTT_1_0", "AttacksTTT_1_1", "Breath0rmal_1_0", 
"Breath0rmal_1_1", "CAsthmaMed_1_0", "CAsthmaMed_1_1", "CCurrentAsthma_1_0", 

"CCurrentAsthma_1_1", "CongColds_1_1", "CoughNight_1_1", 
"CoughWithColds_1_1", 
"EverWheeze_1_0", "EverWheeze_1_1", "Wheeze6M_1_0", "Wheeze6M_1_1", 
"WheezeMostDays_1_0", "WheezeOcc_1_0", "WheezeWithColds_1_0", 
"WheezeWithColds_1_1", "WheezeWithShort_1_0"), class = "factor"), 
    Cluster_prop = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100, 99.4219653, 98.8439306, 95.3757225, 94.7976879, 
    83.2369942, 79.1907514, 53.7572254, 50.867052, 50.867052, 
    100, 100, 100, 93.103448, 89.655172, 86.206897, 86.206897, 
    82.758621, 79.310345, 79.310345), Population = c(96.131528, 
    78.143133, 63.636364, 95.16441, 60.928433, 67.891683, 97.485493, 
    89.555126, 62.669246, 90.32882, 39.071567, 94.584139, 95.16441, 
    36.363636, 37.330754, 68.665377, 32.108317, 43.520309, 21.856867, 
    42.166344, 39.071567, 32.108317, 37.330754, 9.864603, 68.665377, 
    21.856867, 5.415861, 43.520309, 36.363636, 4.83559), Cluster = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var", "Cluster_prop", 
"Population", "Cluster"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), vars = "Cluster", drop = 
TRUE, indices = list(
0:9, 10:19, 20:29), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L, 10L), biggest_group_size = 
10L, labels = structure(list(
Cluster = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame", vars = 
"Cluster", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Cluster"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Many thanks for any advice!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second (**EDIT** and third) issue(s):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
str_sub(str, start = -1, end = -1)

cl2 <- cl1 %>% mutate(Shape = str_sub(Var, start = -1, end = -1))


ggplot(cl2, aes(x=Cluster_prop, y=reorder(Var, Cluster_prop)))+
  geom_segment(aes(yend=Var), xend=0, colour="grey50")+
  geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=Cluster, shape = Shape))+
  geom_point(aes(x = Population), size = 2, color = "black")+
  facet_grid(Cluster~., scales="free_y", space="free_y") +
  ggtitle("Top 10 Cluster Characteristics: % Children Within Cluster With 
          Feature")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @sara_khan if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Not sure why I can't order my data as per my point one, however, you solved the other issues perfectly. Thank you again!